# How to use a different class from an application's activity?

Tags: java, android, class, android-activity

I created a Java file in the same package as my main activity with a class named `sup`.

Now, I need to use this class in the main activity file.

mainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.phy.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    sup mola = new sup(this);
    mola.as();

}
```

sup.java:

```
package com.example.phy.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class sup {

     public sup(Context context){

        CharSequence text = "Hello toast!";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();

    }
    void as(Context context){

        CharSequence text = "as method";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();
    }

}
```

Do I have to import the class into mainActivity? How?

Answer (score 1):

**sup** class and **MainActivity** class are located in the same package, so you dont need to import anything,  BUT you are calling a method of the classs sup in no defined scope... it would be better if you move this

```
sup mola = new sup(this);
mola.as();
```

inside of the  on create method so like:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        sup mola = new sup(this);
        mola.as();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Import is not needed if MainActivity and `sup` class have the same package name

There's a missing parameter in `mola.as();`
It needs to be: `mola.as(this);`